# Choosing matching treshold for geometry matching

Tags: geometry, research, otsu

I have seen that some researches use Otsu's method in order to select a threshold for geometrical matching ([One such article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/322810602_Incrementally_Detecting_Change_Types_of_Spatial_Area_Object_A_Hierarchical_Matching_Method_Considering_Change_Process)). They refer to [an article that describes such usage](http://ch.whu.edu.cn/EN/abstract/abstract3072.shtml) but it is written in Chinese. Are there any English speaking sources on such usage of Otsu's method? If not, what other method may I use for selecting a matching threshold for matching two datasets?

Example:

I have two sets with polygons, set A and set B. I want to use a distance measure (let it be centroid distance based measure) in order to check if the two polygons have the same "position". How do I select a similarity threshold that is appropriate?